# Why is git revert telling me "bad revision" when I use a commit hash?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

I am trying to revert to an earlier git commit but get the error "bad revision".  Why?

Here is a transcript (with author names removed):

```
Ellen@ELLEN-PC /c/Users/Susan Mills/git/hello-github (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Ellen@ELLEN-PC /c/Users/Susan Mills/git/hello-github (master)
$ git log | head
commit e3eb30cc7ca6d4cd10de755b63821cad75da1e83
Date:   Wed Feb 5 17:54:32 2014 -0800

    I changed my greeting.

commit 063ac580e28bab524286dac7b0a8f88d9e7d365f
Date:   Mon Feb 3 07:53:19 2014 -0800

Ellen@ELLEN-PC /c/Users/Susan Mills/git/hello-github (master)
$ git revert 9e7d365f
fatal: bad revision '9e7d365f'
```

Why am I getting "bad revision", and what should I do?  I am using `git bash` on Windows 7  with my origin on github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use the short version of a SHA1, you use the **prefix**, not the suffix.  So you actually want to say:

```
git revert 063ac580
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the beginning of the hash as identification, as in:

```
git revert 063ac580e2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to revert that doesn't exist.  The SHA that starts with 9e7d365f is not in your repository.

Comment: Is not possible to restore a revision that was removed from the repo? Like if the commit was deleted by a forced push to the remote repo - the revision id is seen in the activity logs but no such revision exists.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But that is not the problem that the OP had.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I copied the full SHA from GitHub. **However, that commit didn't exist anymore** since when the PR was merged, GitHub created a different commit with a different hash.

I run `git log` to obtain the actual SHA, and now it worked.